# Filter Query Post by Custom Fields(by date)

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, meta-query

I want to filter query_post using the 2 meta keys `start_date` and `end_date`, i want to get my posts to divide it by upcoming events and past events.
`start_date` and `end_date` is stored in the timestamp format

here is my approach i tried but it doesn't work:

```
        $metaq = array(
                    'key'       => 'start_date',
                    'value'     => strtotime("today"),
                    'compare'   => '>='
                );

        $args = array('category_name' => 'events',
                      'order' => 'desc',
                      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                      'meta_query' => $metaq);

        query_posts($args);
```

but it just displays all post which have the category of `events`.

what i want is to get the upcoming events and past events by using `start_date` and `end_date`

every post that has not started yet are categorized as upcoming events
every post that has ended are cateforized as past events

Comment: `meta_query` is an array of arrays, you just have a single array. also, never use `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, your query arguments are slightly off - [`meta_query` should be an *array of arrays*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name' => 'events',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'start_date',
            'value'   => strtotime( 'today' ),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type'    => 'UNSIGNED', // Ensure MySQL treats the value as numeric
        )
    )
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        // Your template code
    }
}
```